# Spring boot CORS not allowing my requests

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I have a system where the front-ed is react and the backend is spring boot.
I have added the CORS conditions as per the available tutorials, but getting the below error always:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/my-shops/shop/list-shops' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Server log:**

```
2023-07-25T15:20:42.896+05:30 ERROR 16964 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.shop.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt  : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

***Headers:***

**General**:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:8080/my-shops/shop/list-shops
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
401
Remote Address:
[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2023 10:13:21 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Request**

```
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:
GET
Connection:
keep-alive
Host:
localhost:8080
Origin:
http://localhost:3000
Referer:
http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

**Code:**

This is my **controller class**:

```
@Log
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my-shops/shop")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
public class ShopController {

    @Autowired
    ShopService shopService;
    @Autowired
    private AddressService addressService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    AuthUserRepository authUserRepository;

    @PostMapping("/add-address")
    public ResponseEntity<Address> createAddress() {
        addressService.addAddress(new Address());
        return  new ResponseEntity<Address>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/list-shops")
    public List<ShopResponse> getShops() {
        List<Shop> shopList = shopService.getAllShop();
        List<ShopResponse> shopResponses = shopList.stream().map(shop -> {
            ShopResponse response = new ShopResponse();
            response.setId(shop.getId());
            response.setAddress1(shop.getAddress().getAddress1());
            response.setName(shop.getName());
            response.setEmail(shop.getEmail());
            response.setMobile(shop.getMobile());
            response.setDescription(shop.getDescription());
            response.setCreatedDate(shop.getCreatedAt().toString());
            response.setCreatedUser(shop.getCreatedBy().getUsername());
            response.setLastUpdatedDate(shop.getUpdatedAt().toString());
            response.setLastUpdatedUser(shop.getUpdatedBy().getUsername());
            response.setCity(shop.getAddress().getCity());
            response.setDistrict(shop.getAddress().getDistrict());
            response.setState(shop.getAddress().getState());
            response.setPincode(shop.getAddress().getPincode());
            return response;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return shopResponses;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/add-shop")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addShop(@RequestBody Shop shop) {
        String currentUserName = AuthHelper.getCurrentUserName();
        Optional<AuthUser> loggedInUser = authUserRepository.findByUsername(currentUserName);
        System.out.println(shop);

        Address addressObject = null;
        if (loggedInUser.isPresent()) {
            AuthUser authUser = loggedInUser.get();
            shop.setCreatedBy(authUser);
            shop.setUpdatedBy(authUser);
            addressObject = shop.getAddress();
            addressObject.setCreatedBy(authUser);
            addressObject.setUpdatedBy(authUser);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY);
        }

        Address address = addressService.addAddress(addressObject);
        shop.setAddress(address);

        log.info(shop.toString());
        shopService.addShop(shop);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Shop created successfully!!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

this is my **CorsConfig** class:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

this is my **WebSecurityConfig**  class:

```
@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableMethodSecurity
//(securedEnabled = true,
//jsr250Enabled = true,
//prePostEnabled = true) // by default

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig { // extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
  }

//  @Override
//  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
//    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
//  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

      authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

      return authProvider;
  }

//  @Bean
//  @Override
//  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
//    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
//  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

//  @Override
//  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
//      .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
//      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
//      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
//      .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
//      .anyRequest().authenticated();
//
//    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
//  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
          auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
              .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
//                  .requestMatchers("/my-shops/**").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());


    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

This is **AuthTokenFilter** class

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Autowired
  private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      String jwt = parseJwt(request);
      if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

This is my **AuthEntryPointJwt** class:

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
  }

}
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Post the headers your backend is returning

Comment: @possum Question updated with headers.

Comment: Your preflight OPTIONS request is what will return the allowed origins, but it's returning unauthorized.  You need to change your permissions such that an OPTIONS call to that endpoint can return the correct header.